# Django как поменять сообщения об ошибках. "Please fill out this field"

Tags: python, django, forms

Мне необходимо поменять сообщение об ошибке. Как я могу это сделать?
Я использую следующий код для создания формы регистрации:

```
class RegisterUserForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))


    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('name', 'username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2')


        help_texts = {
            'username': None,
            'password1': None,
        }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RegisterUserForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['username'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
        self.fields['password1'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
        self.fields['password2'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
```

Вот, что нужно поменять:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Эти ошибки отображает браузер, Django тут ни при чём

Comment: Как сделать, чтобы это дошло до браузера и он отобразил?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте в Meta добавить

```
error_messages = {
            "name": {                
                "required": "Введите имя же!",
            },
```

Comment: Этот текст до браузера не дойдёт

Answer (score 0):

Это браузерная ошибка, которая по-разному отображается в разных браузерах. Чтобы убрать эти предупреждения нужно в тэг **form** добавить **novalidate**. А потом уже самому добавлять валидаторы

```
<!--Register-->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="container_for_form">
            <p id="reg">Регистрация</p>
            <form method="POST" action="" novalidate>
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ form.as_p }}
                <input type=submit id=submit value=Зарегистрироваться>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```